# List of valid operations in Tensorflow

Tags: c, api, tensorflow

I am using (learning) Tensorflow through the eager C API, or to be even more precise through a FreePascal wrapper around it.
When I want to do e.g. a matrix multiplication, I call

`TFE_Execute(Op, @OutTensH, @NumOutVals, Status);`

where Op.Op_Name is 'MatMul'. I have a couple of other instructions figured out, e.g. 'Transpose', 'Softmax', 'Inv', etc., but I do not have a complete list. In particular I want to get the determinant of a matrix, but cannot find it (assume it exists). I tried to find it on the web, as well as in the source on GitHub, but no success.
In Python there is tf.linalg.det, but already in C++ API I do not find it.

1. Could someone direct me to a place where I can find a complete list of supported operations?
2. Can someone tell me how to calculate the determinant with Tensorflow?

Edit: On Gaurav's request I attach a small program. As said above, it is in Pascal, and calls the C API through a wrapper. I therefore copied also the relevant part of the wrapper here (full version: https://macpgmr.github.io/). The set-up works, the "only" question is that I do not find a list of supported operations.

```
// A minimal program to transpose a matrix

program test;
uses
  SysUtils,
  TF;
var
  Tensor:TTensor;
begin
  Tensor:=TTensor.CreateSingle([2,1],[1.0,2.0]);
  writeln('Before transpose ',Tensor.Dim[0],' x ',Tensor.Dim[1]);         // 2 x 1
  Tensor:=Tensor.Temp.ExecOp('Transpose',TTensor.CreateInt32([1,0]).Temp);
  writeln('After transpose  ',Tensor.Dim[0],' x ',Tensor.Dim[1]);         // 1 x 2
  FreeAndNil(Tensor);                                                            
end.


// extract from TF.pas ( (C) Phil Hess ). It basically re-packages the operation
// and calls the relevant C TFE_Execute, with the same operation name passed on:
// in our case 'Transpose'.
// I am looking for a complete list of supported operations.

function TTensor.ExecOp(const OpName  : string;
                              Tensor2 : TTensor = nil;
                              Tensor3 : TTensor = nil;
                              Tensor4 : TTensor = nil) : TTensor;
var
  Status     : TF_StatusPtr;
  Op         : TFE_OpPtr;
  NumOutVals : cint;
  OutTensH   : TFE_TensorHandlePtr;
begin
  Result := nil;
  Status := TF_NewStatus();
  Op := TFE_NewOp(Context, PAnsiChar(OpName), Status);
  try
    if not CheckStatus(Status) then
      Exit;
     {Add operation input tensors}
    TFE_OpAddInput(Op, TensorH, Status);
    if not CheckStatus(Status) then
      Exit;
    if Assigned(Tensor2) then  {Operation has 2nd tensor input?}
      begin
      TFE_OpAddInput(Op, Tensor2.TensorH, Status);
      if not CheckStatus(Status) then
        Exit;
      end;
    if Assigned(Tensor3) then  {Operation has 3rd tensor input?}
      begin
      TFE_OpAddInput(Op, Tensor3.TensorH, Status);
      if not CheckStatus(Status) then
        Exit;
      end;
    if Assigned(Tensor4) then  {Operation has 4th tensor input?}
      begin
      TFE_OpAddInput(Op, Tensor4.TensorH, Status);
      if not CheckStatus(Status) then
        Exit;
      end;
     {Set operation attributes}
    TFE_OpSetAttrType(Op, 'T', DataType);  //typically result type same as input's
    if OpName = 'MatMul' then
      begin
      TFE_OpSetAttrBool(Op, 'transpose_a', #0);  //default (False)
      TFE_OpSetAttrBool(Op, 'transpose_b', #0);  //default (False)
      end
    else if OpName = 'Transpose' then
      TFE_OpSetAttrType(Op, 'Tperm', Tensor2.DataType)  //permutations type
    else if OpName = 'Sum' then
      begin
      TFE_OpSetAttrType(Op, 'Tidx', Tensor2.DataType);  //reduction_indices type
      TFE_OpSetAttrBool(Op, 'keep_dims', #0);          //default (False)
      end
    else if (OpName = 'RandomUniform') or (OpName = 'RandomStandardNormal') then
      begin
      TFE_OpSetAttrInt(Op, 'seed', 0);           //default
      TFE_OpSetAttrInt(Op, 'seed2', 0);          //default
      TFE_OpSetAttrType(Op, 'dtype', TF_FLOAT);  //for now, use this as result type
      end
    else if OpName = 'OneHot' then
      begin
      TFE_OpSetAttrType(Op, 'T', Tensor3.DataType);  //result type must be same as on/off
      TFE_OpSetAttrInt(Op, 'axis', -1);              //default
      TFE_OpSetAttrType(Op, 'TI', DataType);         //indices type
      end;
    NumOutVals := 1;
    try

      // **** THIS IS THE ACTUAL CALL TO THE C API, WHERE Op HAS THE OPNAME

      TFE_Execute(Op, @OutTensH, @NumOutVals, Status);

      // ***********************************************************************

    except on e:Exception do
      raise Exception.Create('TensorFlow unable to execute ' + OpName +
                             ' operation: ' + e.Message);
    end;
    if not CheckStatus(Status) then
      Exit;
    Result := TTensor.CreateWithHandle(OutTensH);
  finally
    if Assigned(Op) then
      TFE_DeleteOp(Op);
    TF_DeleteStatus(Status);
     {Even if exception occurred, don't want to leave any temps dangling}
    if Assigned(Tensor2) and Tensor2.IsTemp then
      Tensor2.Free;
    if Assigned(Tensor3) and Tensor3.IsTemp then
      Tensor3.Free;
    if Assigned(Tensor4) and Tensor4.IsTemp then
      Tensor4.Free;
    if IsTemp then
      Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hi Jollytall, Can you please provide some example of your code, it will be helpful for others to better understand your question and what are you trying to ask.
Please read [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks. I added a small code, with a part of the wrapper, showing where the actual call is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can obtain the list of valid operation names from Python:

```py
from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import op_def_registry
registered_ops = op_def_registry.get_registered_ops()
valid_op_names = sorted(registered_ops.keys())
print(len(valid_op_names))  # Number of operation names in TensorFlow 2.0
1223
print(*valid_op_names, sep='\n')
# Abort
# Abs
# AccumulateNV2
# AccumulatorApplyGradient
# AccumulatorNumAccumulated
# AccumulatorSetGlobalStep
# AccumulatorTakeGradient
# Acos
# Acosh
# Add
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it is a good starting point. I voted for it, but it is not displayed being to new to SO.

Comment: @jollytall That is okay, you do not get the [privilege of voting up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) until you have 15 points of reputation. However, you can always mark an answer as accepted (green tick) if you think it is the solution to your problem (but it is okay to not accept an answer if you still do not feel your problem is solved).

Comment: I gave the green tick, as I basically got a list of supported operations. It does not give the list of parameters though /I did not ask :-(/, but it seems that the tensorflow::ops:: methods (C++ API) are based on the list of available, standard operations, so that helps. I still find it very strange that the C interface has no documentation. It also seems that there is no Determinant operation in C, C++, it only exists in Python.

Comment: @jollytall In the code above, you can do  e.g.`registered_ops['Add']` to see the "operation definition", which gives you more information. The op for the determinant is called [`MatrixDeterminant`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/core/ops/linalg_ops.cc#L291-L307) - name Python functions do not always match the op name (some are wrapped to make it easier to use, some are exported with different names, and there are [renames](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/tools/compatibility/renames_v2.py#L747-L748) between 1.x and 2.x).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was really the information, I was looking for. And on the link, I can directly find the parameters too.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime, I found the description file of TensorFlow at: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/ops/ops.pbtxt. This includes all the operations and their detailed specification.
If someone is interested in a pascal interface to TF, I created one at https://github.com/zsoltszakaly/tensorflowforpascal.